# How can I add a text link just below the legend box in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

I would like to add a text link just below the last item of vertical legend on a pie chart. 
I have tried using a function inside LabelFormatter but not experienced with javascript to do the function as wanted. Can someone help how to accomplish this?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    labelFormatter: function() {
      if (this.isLast) {
        return this + "<br> <a href=\"link\">Text</a>";
      }
    },
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 61.41,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }, {
      name: 'Internet Explorer',
      y: 11.84
    }, {
      name: 'Firefox',
      y: 10.85
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      y: 4.67
    }, {
      name: 'Safari',
      y: 4.18
    }, {
      name: 'Other',
      y: 7.05
    }]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `labelFormatter` function you have access to `this`.

> As a hint, if you use `console.log(this)` inside the function, it will display in the debugger console everything you have access to.

For your case, if you want to know if you are on the last legend item you can compare `this.index` (the index of the legend) with `this.series.data.length - 1` (the number of data items... the *-1* is because the index is offset to zero).

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-stackoverflow-60908009-o3ftp

```js
labelFormatter: function() {
  // if current legend is the last one
  // display the legend name
  // followed by a link on a second line
  if (this.index === this.series.data.length - 1) {
    return (
      this.name +
      '<br> <a style="color: #0c6def; text-decoration: underline;" href="link">Clickable link!</a>'
    );
  }
  // otherwise just display the legend name
  return this.name;
}
```

I've added some styling to the link so that it actually look like a link otherwise it look like the other elements of the legend.

Comment: Thanks, that perfect to display the extra text after the last item but the link does not work it serves only as the link for the last item of pie chart enabling and disabling. Look how it is on the link.
https://jsfiddle.net/Le48f1ay/
Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the link by using `Highcharts. SVGRenderer` class. For example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var legend = this.legend,
      legendGroup = legend.group;

    this.renderer.text(
      '<a href="https://www.google.pl/">Google</a>',
      legendGroup.translateX + legend.padding,
      legendGroup.translateY + legend.legendHeight + legend.padding,
      true
    ).add();
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4953/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text